# Do the usage of antiperspirants causes cysts

Tags: dermatology, side-effects, hygiene, perspiration, cysts

Does the continuous usage of antiperspirants causes cysts if so what happens if the person continues to use the antiperspirant will it result in any other side effects worsening the condition.